# Can Queueable Apex Jobs Run in Parallel?

Tags: apex, queueable-interface

I've got a queueable Apex class that can create parent records for sources records passed into it.

It maintains a map as it goes so that if two source records should relate to the same parent and it doesn't find a parent in the database,  it can check to see if it's created one in memory already.

### Issue

This queueable job is queued up using `Apex.enqueueJob` from a trigger context, i.e. after source records are inserted/updated. During a dataload the matching failed, and two sources that should have resulted in a single parent actually generated separate parent records.

### Testing

Deleting the parent records and running the same code manually on the two sources together resulted in the correct operation proving that the cache map is working as expected.

Deleting the new parent record, running the code manually on the two source records separately also returns the correct result: an account is created for the first, the second one finds the same parent via SOQL and lives happily ever after.

### Questionable Conclusion

The account IDs initially generated were sequential. Given that the cache map works on the source records and generates the correct result I'm lead to believe that the two source records were processed in separate batches of 200 from the trigger, perhaps at the end of one and start of the next, but if everything still ran sequentially with the queueable job the second would have picked up the correct account via SOQL.

Either I've got a logic bug that I still need to find that my testing has failed to reproduce, or the queueable jobs can run side by side. The former is quite likely, but I want to know if two jobs can run simultaneously because if so I'm going to have to reconsider the implementation. **So, can Apex Queueable jobs run in parllel?**

```
    Map<String, Map<Object, Account>> fieldToValueToAccount = new Map<String, Map<Object, Account>>();
    Map<Customer_Source__c, Account> sourceToAccount = new Map<Customer_Source__c, Account>();
    Map<Id, Account> accountsToUpdate = new Map<Id, Account>();

    activeRuleNumbers.sort();

    if(activeRuleNumbers.size() == 0)
        return;

    for(Customer_Source__c source : records)
    {
        String whereClause = '';
        List<String> ruleFields = new List<String>();

        // only query on rules that are active, and that have a value in the record being tested
        for(Integer ruleNumber : activeRuleNumbers)
        {
            String ruleField = 'MatchRule' + ruleNumber + '__c';

            if(source.get(ruleField) == null || (String)source.get(ruleField) == '')
                continue;

            ruleFields.add(ruleField);
            whereClause += ' or ' + ruleField + ' = \''  + source.get(ruleField) + '\' ';
        }

        if(ruleFields.size() == 0)
        {
            continue;
        }

        whereClause = whereClause.removeStart(' or ');

        String query = 'select Id, Customer__c from Customer_Source__c '
                            + ' where Customer__c != null and (' +  whereClause + ') '
                            + ' limit 1 ';

        System.debug(query);
        System.debug(source);

        List<Customer_Source__c> matches = Database.query(query);

        if(matches.size() > 0)
        {
            // found one, map it, bam. Next!
            trackAccountChange(source, matches[0].Customer__c, accountsToUpdate);
            source.Customer__c = matches[0].Customer__c;
            sourcesToUpdate.add(source);
            continue;
        }

        Account acct = null;

        // check the populated match fields for this source against our map to see if an account
        // has already been created that this source would relate to
        for(String field : ruleFields)
        {
            String sourceValue = String.valueOf(source.get(field)).toLowerCase();

            System.Debug('Searching for ' + sourceValue + ' in map for field ' + field);

            if(fieldToValueToAccount.get(field) == null)
            {
                System.Debug('No acount map found');
                continue;
            }

            acct = fieldToValueToAccount.get(field).get(sourceValue);

            if(acct != null)
            {
                System.Debug('Found account in map: ' + acct);
                break;
            }
        }

        // no account found, create a new one
        if(acct == null)
        {
            System.Debug('Creating new account');
            acct = new Account(RecordTypeId = personAccountRTID);
        }

        // map this source's values to the account found/created in the uber map
        for(String field : ruleFields)
        {
            String sourceValue = String.valueOf(source.get(field)).toLowerCase();

            if(fieldToValueToAccount.get(field) == null)
            {
                fieldToValueToAccount.put(field, new Map<Object, Account>{sourceValue => acct});
            }
            else
            {
                fieldToValueToAccount.get(field).put(sourceValue, acct);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Added the stuff that deals with the mapping. Probably missing a little context here but it's all a bit big and hairy to post in full :)

Comment: Ohhh. This is a fun question. Here I go... (be back in a few).

Comment: Glad you're on it. Wanted to try and reproduce but just boarded a flight.... Expect you'll have it wrapped up by the time I'm online again!

Comment: Safe travels, and that was actually pretty easy to verify. I've learned something new today!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes, queueable methods can run in parallel. As a proof of concept, here's some code that I wrote:

```
public class TenSecondQueueable implements Queueable {
    public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, DateTime.now());
        Long start = DateTime.now().getTime();
        while(DateTime.now().getTime()-start<10000);
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, DateTime.now());
    }
}
```

This method will run for approximately 10 seconds. I then ran this execute anonymous script:

```
System.enqueueJob(new TenSecondQueueable());
System.enqueueJob(new TenSecondQueueable());
```

The resulting output for both scripts was as follows:

```
>>>> JOB 1 <<<<
19:56:22.0 (4570498)|USER_DEBUG|[3]|ERROR|2017-03-22 00:56:22
19:56:32.4 (10004427521)|USER_DEBUG|[6]|ERROR|2017-03-22 00:56:32

>>>> JOB 2 <<<<
19:56:22.0 (2618567)|USER_DEBUG|[3]|ERROR|2017-03-22 00:56:22
19:56:32.1 (10001759396)|USER_DEBUG|[6]|ERROR|2017-03-22 00:56:32
```

As you can see, they both started and ended at the exact same time. Mind you, there's also no guarantee this will always happen. However, it's safe to say that it certainly *can* and *will* happen.

---

Odds are, you will probably want to use a locking algorithm to prevent this from happening. I think you'll probably want to add a sentry object (a record you can use to hold a mutex lock), so that the each additional action will need to wait. For example, you might add this near the beginning of your code:

```
    insert new Mutex__c();
    Mutex__c[] lock;
    while(lock == null) {
        try {
            lock = [SELECT Id FROM Mutex__c LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE];
        } catch(QueryException e) {

        }
    }
```

As well as clean up near the end of your code:

```
    delete lock;
```

What will happen here is that if the record you inserted was the oldest lock, your code will have the record lock and proceed immediately. If not, it'll wait idly by until the prior Queueable has finished doing what it needs to do. This should prevent any race conditions from Queueables that run close together, although this also essentially prevents more than one queueable running at a time, even if they wouldn't touch the same record(s).

You might also simply be able to get away with using a FOR UPDATE locking statement on your dynamically generated query. This will "probably" be safe enough for most purposes, but you'll need to do some testing.

Comment: if I read this correctly, it is vital that the code hit the `delete lock;`  - no preliminary returns or throwing exceptions to higher levels

Comment: Damn it, figured this would be the answer! A mutex should work, it'll slow things down but the code should be fast enough to keep pace with data loader!

Comment: @cropredy This is just a bare-bones implementation; I've never had reason to implement a mutex in salesforce. If you wanted to, you might swap out the LIMIT 1 for `WHERE Id <= :mutex.Id` (after saving the mutex to a variable, of course), which would allow you to still throw exceptions/governor limits while still having an effective lock.

Comment: @MattLacey The documentation *suggests* that this "shouldn't" happen because of the incremental delay between Queueables, but now we know differently. The More You Know!

Comment: Oh the joys of limits. You may have noticed my code runs a query per record being processed, basically to prevent the query getting hugely OTT, but now with an extra query for the mutex I'm hitting the limit. Fun times ahead!

Comment: @MattLacey Whoops. Well, looks like you might need to scale down the scope size, then. Just make it half the size or something. We get 250,000 asynchronous calls per day, so you should be okay.

Comment: If anybody is interested: we found a more efficient way of doing mutexes using FOR VIEW, which basically is an atomic operation that queries AND updates a field at the same time. That is great because in the above solution we need to do DML to get a mutex, and then you can't do any callouts and that sucks. If there's interest, I could explain how the FOR VIEW solution works in more detail...

Comment: @WillemMulder feel free to add an answer. I'd love to see what you came up with.

Comment: @WillemMulder the `For View` is pretty clever and I confirmed that callouts can be done afterwards. `FOR VIEW` only works with normal SObjects, not custom settings, platform events or custom metadata.

Comment: sfdcfox -- I've read this mutex example over-and-over; the `lock = [SELECT Id FROM Mutex__c LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE];` - where is it documented that this will return the oldest Mutex__c ?  Queries without `order by` have non-deterministic results but `order by` is not available with `FOR UPDATE`.