# How to monitor not yet started jobs of a Queuable chain

Tags: apex, asynchronous, queue, queueable-apex

I am wrapping my head around how to use `Apex Queuable` **as a queue and not as a chain**.

As I understand all the code samples out there, the next job is enqueued after the work of the previous one is done. But that is a chain and not a queue.

I need something where I get the job ids upfront when I enqueue my jobs so I can later monitor their execution.

```
List<Id> jobIds = new List<Id>();

jobIds.add( System.enqueueJob(new FirstRunThis() );
jobIds.add( System.enqueueJob(new ThenThis() );
jobIds.add( System.enqueueJob(new AndThisOneLast() );

...

public List<AsyncApexJob> pollForStatus(List<Id> jobIds) {
    return [SELECT Id, ApexClass.Name, Status 
            AsyncApexJob WHERE Id IN :jobIds ];
}
```

**How can I use Queuable with all its benefits but get some handles for UI polling upfront? If you have code samples, I will send extra love.**

Comment: I think Platform events are the best option. Depending on your use case, you maybe can utilize ChangeDataCapture to not create PlatformEvent just for that

Comment: as a side note would recommend https://github.com/ytiq/apex-queueable-wrapper to ease up chaining or some other solutions to handle potential Limits

Comment: `the next job is enqueued after the work of the previous one is done` not always the case, from what I remember Salesforce can run up to 5 jobs simultaneously depending on your Salesforce Edition. Here is the answer from sfdxfox on it https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/165430/can-queueable-apex-jobs-run-in-parallel

Comment: also found this option for easier chaining https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/188774/chaining-queueables-clarification-practical-usage

Comment: A queue which runs jobs in parallel when you say enqueue() is just a crappy design.Especially if it fails when you do this more than 5 times.

Answer (score 4):

Publish Platform Events in the Queueables and monitor them by subscribing to those.

OK, this adds complications, the biggest being that in the Apex the code runs under a single "service" user. But server-side subscription is done via the familiar trigger handler pattern and client-side subscription has a ready made `lightning-emp-api` component.

So no polling needed, and the Platform Event(s) can carry whatever information you like.

(And if you have lots of logic based on job ids, then the Platform Event could just carry that, being published when the Queueable starts, and being stored somewhere in the data model by an Apex subscriber.)

**PS**

To clarify on the "service" user, though Platform Events might be published via *many* different users, the Apex subscription runs under a *single* user. So for example, DML will be labelled as done by that single user. By default the user is the "Automated Process" user, but you can now nominate a different user; see [Configure the User and Batch Size for Your Platform Event Trigger](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_trigger_config.htm).

Comment: Note that Spring '21 adds the ability to configure trigger-based platform event subscribers to execute with a defined scope size and as a specific user. See [the release notes](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_messaging_trigger_config.htm&type=5&release=230) for details. That said, we haven't managed to get this working in our managed package development at this stage. Also note that platform event metadata has specific limitations around data types and do not support related lists.

Comment: Hi @PhilW, I'll clarify that in the answer: it is still a single user rather than the various users that published the Platform Event. I do have that working now for one of our products, but had to do the setup via the Tooling API in a setup page as this is not yet supported AFAIK in the standard Setup UI.

Comment: Also, be aware that you have a hard limit of 250,000 platform events published per hour in the org, across all publishers.  Depending on how you use PEs elsewhere, using them to log queueable success may push you towards that limit.